# Springboot Testing Junit Assertions

Tags: mockito, junit5, spring-test, assertion, mockmvc

Is it possible to expect 200 or 400 in Springboot tests using MockMvc? When the project runs on different environments,to avoid commenting out code when deploying to different servers.

example below:

```
 .andExpect(is.ok()orclient_error)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void testGetResource() throws Exception {
                      mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/resource"))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().is2xxSuccessful())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isNotEqualTo(404))
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isBadRequest());
    }
}
```

Comment: the question is not clear. do you want to expect different https status based on some property or profile?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Typical test follows given-when-then structure: if request is ok and server has the data then return 200, otherwise return appropriate error. Your proposed test "it either returns success or error" adds little value, you will be better off with 2 or more tests, clearly specifying success or error conditions. You typically dont deploy unit tests to prod servers - unit tests are run using test server (ideally in the same process or on the local machine) - you dont deploy the, to prod.

Comment: Do you want to match multiple statuses, e.g. 200-499? Or do you want to match different statuses based on some config? Why doesn't your test set the required config?